# Trying to work out why this regex is not working? Regex should be less restrictive

Tags: regex

The Text :

```
[prc:tl:plfl]
```

is matched by:

```
\[prc:tl:[^]]*plfl\]
```

However I need to also match:

```
[prc:tl:plfl,tr]
```

Basically "plfl" can appear anywhere in the string after "tl:" and before next "]"

So all of the following should match

```
[prc:tl:plfl,tr]
[prc:tl:tr, plfl]
[prc:tl:tr, plfl,sr]
[prc:tl:plfl,tr, sr, mr]
```

What is missing from my regex?

MAny thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `'\[prc:tl:[^]]*plfl.*\]'` instead.

Comment: _What is missing from my regex?_ -- A `.*`

Comment: Aaah.... I tried "*", but not the ".". Thanks that is great. If you want to post it as an answer then I will mark accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You may match any text other than `]` after `plfl` with a negated character class `[^\]]` (you are actually already using it in the regex):

```
\[prc:tl:[^\]]*?plfl[^\]]*\]
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nii9fL/1/)

**Details**

- `\[prc:tl:` - a `[prc:tl:` substring
- `[^\]]*?` - a negated character class matching any 0+ chars other than `]` as few as possible
- `plfl` - a `plfl` substring
- `[^\]]*` -  any 0+ chars other than `]` as few as possible
- `\]` - a `]` char.

See the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5Bprc%3Atl%3A%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%3Fplfl%5B%5E%5C%5D%5D*%5C%5D):

[image]